# Convert multiple PDF/PNG files to SVG files for Android app development

Tags: android, ios, pdf, svg, png

I have an iOS app which is already out on the App Store and currently developing Android version for it.

I made hundreds of PDF/PNG images for the iOS apps, and I do not want to conver them to SVG files one by one.

Is there any good tool to convert multiple PDF/PNG files to SVG files?

Comment: Why can't you use the png images?

Comment: More importantly, since Android does not use SVG (except for manually creating icons through the Image Asset Wizard), what are you hoping to gain by having them as SVG?